# how to test svg response with jmeter

Tags: xml, svg, jmeter

I'm  trying to automate testing of my web service with JMeter. My service returns data with a mime type of image/svg but JMeter seems to be ignoring the response.

If I reconfigure the output to be image/png then JMeter can correctly display the image but it is really hard to automate the test of correctness against an actual image. With the SVG output I was hoping to be able to use a regexp to test that there were fills of the correct color (and none of the wrong color).

Is there someway to tell JMeter to process an svg response as xml?